# Average answer in selected options by letter value

Tags: html, jquery

Making an genetics planner for the game Rust and have been trying to achieve an average answer based on selected options. See example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hakonjj/nbk5m2sz/3/)

Example: If the first column have two or more of the same, the output should be that answer. In this JSFiddle example answer should be G.

How do I show the average valued letter in each columns on last row?

```
<div class="col-12 genes">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>Select genetics of first plant</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <select id="gene1-1" name="gene1-1" class="geneticsBackground" onchange="average1()">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-2" name="gene1-2" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-3" name="gene1-3" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W" selected>W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-4" name="gene1-4" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-5" name="gene1-5" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-6" name="gene1-6" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H" selected>H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row genesRow">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>Select genetics of second plant</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <select id="gene2-1" name="gene2-1" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-2" name="gene2-2" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-3" name="gene2-3" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-4" name="gene2-4" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X" selected>X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-5" name="gene2-5" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-6" name="gene2-6" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X" selected>X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row genesRow">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>Select genetics of third plant</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <select id="gene3-1" name="gene3-1" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W" selected>W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-2" name="gene3-2" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W" selected>W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-3" name="gene3-3" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X" selected>X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-4" name="gene3-4" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-5" name="gene3-5" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-6" name="gene3-6" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row genesRow">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>Select genetics of fourth plant</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <select id="gene4-1" name="gene4-1" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-2" name="gene4-2" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-3" name="gene4-3" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-4" name="gene4-4" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-5" name="gene4-5" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X" selected>X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-6" name="gene4-6" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row genesRow">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>What you get</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics1" value="G">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics2" value="G">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics3" value="G">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics4" value="Y">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics5" value="Y">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics6" value="Y">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What if there were 2 of each, e.g. G,G,W,W ?

Comment: Hi hakonjj, I can see that you've got a project in progress which you require support on, but not that you've made an attempt to resolve this problem yourself yet. Have you made an attempt to calculate this information? If you have, please provide it. That way we can critique it and you may learn why you should / shouldn't do certain things, and we can help you achieve this.

Comment: Hi @MichaelThompson and thank you for reply. I'm at the very beginning of learning as a hobby and couldnt understand how to calculate by letters and first tried with numbers first which was totally unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the mode of the column when any item changes:

```js
        function mode(arr) {
            return arr.sort((a, b) =>
                arr.filter(v => v === a).length
                - arr.filter(v => v === b).length
            ).pop();
        }

        $('select').change(function () {
            var arr = [];
            var index = $(this).index();
            $(".col-9").each(function () {
                arr.push($(this).children().eq(index).children("option:selected").val());
            });
            
            var xx = mode(arr);

            $(".result").children().eq(index).val(xx);
        });
```

```css
        .outcomeGenetics {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-left: 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .genes {
            padding-top: 1em
        }

        .genesRow {
            padding-top: 1em
        }

        .genes select {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            text-align-last: right;
            padding-right: 17px;
            direction: rtl;
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

        select {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            text-indent: 1px;
            text-overflow: '';
        }

        html {
            background: #e6e9e9;
            background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, rgb(230, 233, 233) 0%, rgb(216, 221, 221) 100%);
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        }

        body {
            background: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
            color: #545454;
            font-family: "Rust", sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 800px;
            padding: 2em 2em 4em;
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6 {
            color: #222;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 1.3;
        }

        h2 {
            margin-top: .5em;
        }

        a {
            color: #0083e8;
        }

        b,
        strong {
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        samp {
            display: none;
        }

        img {
            animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
            background: transparent;
            border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
            border-radius: 4px;
            display: block;
            margin: 1.3em auto;
            max-width: 95%;
        }

        @keyframes colorize {
            0% {
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
                filter: grayscale(100%);
            }

            100% {
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
                filter: grayscale(0%);
            }
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Rust';
            src: url('font/Rust.eot');
            src: url('font/Rust.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                url('font/Rust.svg#Rust') format('svg'),
                url('font/Rust.ttf') format('truetype'),
                url('font/Rust.woff') format('woff'),
                url('font/Rust.woff2') format('woff2');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12 genes">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>Select genetics of first plant</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <select id="gene1-1" name="gene1-1" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-2" name="gene1-2" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-3" name="gene1-3" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W" selected>W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-4" name="gene1-4" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-5" name="gene1-5" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene1-6" name="gene1-6" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H" selected>H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row genesRow">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>Select genetics of second plant</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <select id="gene2-1" name="gene2-1" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-2" name="gene2-2" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-3" name="gene2-3" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-4" name="gene2-4" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X" selected>X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-5" name="gene2-5" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene2-6" name="gene2-6" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X" selected>X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row genesRow">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>Select genetics of third plant</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <select id="gene3-1" name="gene3-1" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W" selected>W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-2" name="gene3-2" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W" selected>W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-3" name="gene3-3" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X" selected>X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-4" name="gene3-4" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-5" name="gene3-5" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene3-6" name="gene3-6" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row genesRow">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>Select genetics of fourth plant</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    <select id="gene4-1" name="gene4-1" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-2" name="gene4-2" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-3" name="gene4-3" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G" selected>G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-4" name="gene4-4" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-5" name="gene4-5" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y">Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X" selected>X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="gene4-6" name="gene4-6" class="geneticsBackground">
                        <option value="G">G</option>
                        <option value="Y" selected>Y</option>
                        <option value="H">H</option>
                        <option value="X">X</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row genesRow">
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    <label>What you get</label>
                </div>
                <div class="result">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics1" value="G">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics2" value="G">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics3" value="G">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics4" value="Y">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics5" value="Y">
                    <input type="text" class="outcomeGenetics" id="genetics6" value="Y">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are a saviour and a saint, Andrew! This worked flawlessy!